# Set value disabled input field

Tags: javascript

I set the value to a disabled input field by using

```
$("input:disabled").val(data);
```

This works perfect. The only problem is that all disabled input are set by this value.

So is there a way to set the value of a specified disabled input field.

Comment: you need id specified... it will affect all input disabled field

Comment: You need some other selector to be specified - id,class,etc. This should be unique to the input field.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just to help clarify and understand what your code is doing, I have broken down the question and shown some examples.

Your following code is trying to get all HTML tags called `<input>` that are "disabled" and setting them to the variable "data"

```
$("input:disabled").val(data);
```

**What you want:**

Specify a unique element by using its ID

```
$("#uniqueID").val(data);
```

Specify a specific set of elements by class

```
$(".elementsWithThisClassName").val(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("input:disabled").val('data'); // Your Code
$("#username").val('real data');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="username" disabled/>
<input type="password" id="password" disabled/>
```

You should set specific id.